# MySQL-libs file conflicts when updating PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update the version of PHP on my CentOS server to 5.3.8.  However, when I run "yum update php" I get a a slew of file conflicts between mysql-libs and mysql.  I've tried uninstalling mysql-server, mysql-devel, and mysql-client and then reinstalling all of them, but when I do that mysqld won't start and isn't writing any errors to /var/log/messages or anywhere else that I can find.  I know it's a recent problem as I didn't have this problem back in July/August.  Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Here's what my console looks like:

```
[root@ip-10-123-23-54 ~]# yum update php
Excluding Packages from none
Finished
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: php = 5.2.4-RightScale for package: php-devel
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.8-2.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.8-2.el5.art for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli = 5.3.8-2.el5.art for package: php
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.8-2.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libedit.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-cli
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.4-RightScale for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.4-RightScale for package: php-pdo
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.8-2.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.3.8-2.el5.art set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libedit.x86_64 0:3.0-2.20090923cvs.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.8-2.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: php-mysql
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.8-2.el5.art set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.18-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                Arch                                               Version                                                                  Repository                                          Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 php                                                    x86_64                                             5.3.8-2.el5.art                                                          atomic                                             1.4 M
Installing for dependencies:
 libedit                                                x86_64                                             3.0-2.20090923cvs.el5.art                                                atomic                                              81 k
 mysql-libs                                             x86_64                                             5.5.18-1.el5.art                                                         atomic                                             1.1 M
Updating for dependencies:
 php-cli                                                x86_64                                             5.3.8-2.el5.art                                                          atomic                                             2.6 M
 php-common                                             x86_64                                             5.3.8-2.el5.art                                                          atomic                                             982 k
 php-devel                                              x86_64                                             5.3.8-2.el5.art                                                          atomic                                             625 k
 php-mysql                                              x86_64                                             5.3.8-2.el5.art                                                          atomic                                             160 k
 php-pdo                                                x86_64                                             5.3.8-2.el5.art                                                          atomic                                             117 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install      2 Package(s)
Update       6 Package(s)
Remove       0 Package(s)

Total size: 7.0 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.18-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what you get for installing RHEL5 packages on CentOS :)
Is there a reason you have MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64 instead of CentOS native MySQL package?

All in all I'd say remove MySQL-server-community-5.1.55-1.rhel5.x86_64 and install CentOS's stock MySQL if there is no particular reason.

Comment: The server is an EC2 instance spun up in Rightscale from a LAMP Rightscale server template, hence the RHEL package which is default in the template (though I wish Rightscale would update there templatew because they are waaaaay old).   Also, I've tried uninstalling the RHEL package and rpm installing a generic MySQL package from MySQL's website and the problem I run into there is I can't get the service to start after installation and its not logging anywhere that I can find to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Try uninstalling the RHEL package and do yum install mysql-server, then updating php. You need to bring your packages in sync. CentOS has it's own mysql, why mysql's website or RHEL?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error with the mysql-libs issue when upgrading PHP from 5.3 to 5.4 on CentOS 6.2. Here is my procedures to solve the issue. I maintained the mysql server v5.5 on the server without upgrading

- Install remi repo

`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

`wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm`

`sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm`

- Install compat-mysql55

`yum --enablerepo=remi-test install compat-mysql55` (the version number 55 is due to mysql server 5.5 on my server)

`sudo yum --enablerepo=remi update php-\*`

- Upgrade PHP
  `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi update php-\*`

If that fails, please try to install MySQL-shared-compat-[version]-1.el6.[arch].rpm before the step of Install compat-mysql55. Where [version] is the mysql server version on your box and [arch] is the architecture of the box. e.g., MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.23-1.el6.x86_64.rpm. Please google to find the URL for the file.